# Grails - using super class by select from base class

Tags: java, grails, select, hql, grails-orm

I have domain class like this:

```
Base {
    filed filed11
}

Super extends Base{
    Right filed2
}

Supers extends Base{
    Left filed2
}
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
from Base b 
  left join Super as s 
    with b.id = s.id where s.field2.isOk == true
```

The question is: how can join super class with base clase in one query ?
Beacuse my query not works.

Answer (score 2):

A join is needed to go from one entity to another, associated entity. You don't have any association here: `Super` extends `Base`. It's inheritance, and thus Super **is a** Base.

```
from Super s where s.field2.isOK == true
```

To explain with an analogy:

You don't ask *"Give me all the clothes having a Shoe with shoelaces"*. You ask *"Give me all the shoes with shoelaces"*. Because a Clothe doesn't have a Shoe (and vice versa). Shoe *is a* Clothe.